# Angular Formly - Error messages do not appear

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Below is a simple example of my field:

```
{
  key: 'name',
  type: 'input',
  validators: {
    nameValid: {
      expression: function(viewValue, modelValue){
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        return (some condition on value);
      },
      message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid string"'
    }
  },
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Name',
    placeholder: 'Name',
    options: [],
    required: true
  },
  validation: {
    messages: {
      required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
        return scope.to.label + ' is required';
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I have validation messages set for both a specific condition, and also the required field condition. However, if my condition isn't met or the field is not filled in, no error messages appear. The field simply turns red (as it should), but how can I get it to also display my error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add error template and then retry, It's better if you can provide a jsbin link to debug.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom-messages.html">
    <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="options.formControl.$error" ng-if="options.validation.errorExistsAndShouldBeVisible">
        <div class="error-message" ng-message="{{::name}}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages">
            {{message(options.formControl.$viewValue, options.formControl.$modelValue, this)}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I was missing an error template. Would you be able to step me through (perhaps line by line) how this works?

Comment: you can actually pick any example given at angular-formly page. http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/error-summary which would show error message and also error summary incase if you're interested

Answer (score -1):

You can set the wrapper to input field in app.config function to show error message.

```
app.config(function (formlyConfigProvider)({
      formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
         name: 'validation',
         types: ['input'],
         template:'<formly-transclude></formly-transclude><div ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="form.$submitted || options.formControl.$touched" class="error-messages"><div ng-message="{{ ::name }}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" class="message">{{ message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}</div></div>'
        //templateUrl: 'error-messages.html'
});}};
```